# How to implement swipe to delete action for listview/recyclerview in Xamarin Android native project

Tags: android, xamarin.android

This could be duplicate of similar question. But I have reseached a lot but could not find a satisfactory answer. In my current project requirement, I want to implement swipe gesture for a listview(or recyclerview). For example in each row item if user swipe left the item it will reveal delete option. Otherwise if user swipe right it will reveal make favourite option.

Please suggest what will be approach and if any good article is available on the same it will be very helpful. I am looking for the implementation in Xamarin.Android native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example in each row item if user swipe left the item it will reveal delete option.

If you want to implement this action, I suggest you can use **Xamarin.Android Swipe menu Listview**.

The detailed info, you can take a look the demo:

https://github.com/WahidNasri/SwipeMenuListView-Sharp

Comment: Thanks @Cherry Bu, This is one solution initially I faced issue to integrate the same into solution so I used https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/master/Android/AndroidSwipeLayout
There is a nuget for this component available: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.AndroidSwipeLayout